# AudioRecord read returns strange values

Tags: android, audio, android-sensors, android-audiorecord

I am trying to build some kind of sound-meter to the Android platform. (i am using HTC wildfire) I use the `AudioRecord` class for that goal, however it seems that the
values that are being returned from its "read" are not reasonable.

This is how i created the AudioRecord object:

```
int minBufferSize = 
         AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHz,
                                      android.media.AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                      android.media.AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

audioRecored = new AudioRecord( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,          
                                44100, 
                                android.media.AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                android.media.AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                minBufferSize );
```

This is how i try to read data from it:

```
    short[] audioData = new short[bufferSize];
    int offset =0;
    int shortRead = 0;
    int sampleToReadPerGet = 1000;//some value in order to avoid momentaraly nosies.

    //start tapping into the microphone
    audioRecored.startRecording();

   //start reading from the microphone to an internal buffer - chuck by chunk
   while (offset < sampleToReadPerGet)
   {
            shortRead = audioRecored.read(audioData, offset ,sampleToReadPerGet - offset);
            offset += shortRead;
   }

   //stop tapping into the microphone
   audioRecored.stop();

    //average the buffer
    int averageSoundLevel = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sampleToReadPerGet ; i++)
    {
        averageSoundLevel += audioData[i];          
    }
    averageSoundLevel /= sampleToReadPerGet;
```

What are those values? are they decibels?

Edit:
The values goes from -200 to 3000.
The value of shortRead is sampleToReadPerGet (1000).

Comment: What values are you getting?  Surely you're just getting back 16-bit PCM samples.

Comment: What is the value of 'shortRead' after calling to read?

Comment: Added the values to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what "those values" you are referring to, the raw output or the averaged values, but the raw output are instantaneous amplitude levels. It's important to realize that such values are not referenced to anything in particular. That is, just because you are reading 20, does not tell you 20 of what.

Taking the average of these values doesn't make any sense, because those values swing above and below zero. Do it long enough and you'll just get zero.

It might make sense to take the average of the squares, and then find the square root of the average. This is called the RMS. However, without a fixed buffer size to average over, this is hazardous at best.

To measure dB, you will have to use the formula dB = 20 log_10 (|A|/A_r) where A is the amplitude and A_r is the reference amplitude -- clearly, you must decide what you are referencing (you can calibrate the HTC, or measure against the maximum level or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

You should not get negative values. The values span 16 or 8 bits, so your max is about 32000 or something. The values have no units.

Also, I recommend root-mean-squared instead of an average for determining volume. It is more stable.

What you should try:

- Increase the buffer size by 3: Your app may not be reading it fast
  enough so you need some space. Otherwise you might be getting some
  buffer overflow errors (which you are not checking for in your code)
- Try the code in [gast-lib](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/audio/record/AudioClipRecorder.java): It helps you periodically record audio and also provides you an AsyncTask.
- Root mean squared:

> ```
> public static double rootMeanSquared(short[] nums)
> {
>     double ms = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
>     {
>         ms += nums[i] * nums[i];
>     }
>     ms /= nums.length;
>     return Math.sqrt(ms);
> }
> ```

Comment: actually it does after hours of tweaking ;)